# Double extension file

Tags: batch, batch-file, file-extension, temporary-files

i don't know from where I got this file in my computer's temp folder `C:\USERS\xxxxxxxxxx\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\TMPE8FE.TMP.BAT` is it some kind of malware? if yes, then how should i resolve this.

Comment: Why not open in notepad and put the file code in your question?

Answer (score 2):

> is it some kind of malware?

Maybe. Maybe not.

Temporary directories are often used by malware to hide its files under random names. But they are also used by legitimate programs and randomizing names is a good method of avoiding collisions. The suspicious double-extension suggests the former, though: it could be an attempt to hide an executable.

Run a system scan with your antivirus program and maybe something like Malwarebytes. If it finds anything: [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/q/100360)